# Running chef-solo gives HTTPServerException 404 "Not Found

Tags: vagrant, chef-infra, chef-recipe, chef-solo

I am trying to provision VM by chef. I have written default.rb scripts and kept the files which i want to copy to the VM.

```
 cookbook_file "/etc/hosts" do
     source "etc_hosts"
     mode 0644
     owner "root"
     group "root"
   end
end
```

This fails with below error..

```
 Error executing action `create` on resource 'cookbook_file[/etc/hosts]'
==> default:     ================================================================================
==> default:
==> default:     Net::HTTPServerException
==> default:     ------------------------
==> default:     404 "Not Found"
```

The file is correctly placed.
When tried to run the chef script again this is success.
It fails on alternate runs. Anything which I may be missing ?

Comment: What is the next resource statement? Also, can you please update the above error with more logs?

Comment: In the snippet you provide, everything is commented with `#` so what do you expect to run ? Its not clear with so little information

Comment: There is not much logs except 404 not found this is on alternate runs on the next run it is resolved.

Comment: @MohitArora - Can you please update on which resource you are calling next in your recipe i.e, "default.rb"?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you didn't actually have that commented out, make sure you have the file content at `files/etc_hosts` in the cookbook.

Comment: I do have.Also it gets successful on the alternate run.It fails intermittently

Comment: What you see is what you get, if it says the file isn't there then it's probably not there. Check whatever system you are using to sync solo files around.